# Tags for games with different localized names

Tags: discussion, tags

[This question](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/15141/whats-the-difference-between-the-oriental-market-building-and-the-regular-sma) about "Dawn of Discovery" was retagged to also contain the "Anno 1404" tag. They refer to the same game, called Anno 1404 everywhere but the US, where it is called Dawn of Discovery.

I think the Anno 1404 tag is helpful as many people only know the game by its original name. But we now have two tags that refer to exactly the same game, which is probably not ideal.

How should we proceed in such cases?

Comment: We figured [early on](http://meta.gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/165/tagging-games-that-have-more-than-one-title) that there may not be a good "general" solution for this scenario, so it's better to handle these case-by-case. I don't mind revisiting that decision, though.

Comment: Have you proposed a synonym? We need to pick a direction...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I wanted to make this synonym proposal:

```
anno-1404 ← dawn-of-discovery
```

and got:

> Failed to propose synonym: Version specific synonyms can only be created by moderators

Thank you, Stack Overflow :|

Comment: I'm not sure a synonym is the best solution here, some people will only know the game as Dawn of Discovery, others will only know it as Anno 1404. This will confuse some part of our users for sure.

Comment: @Fabian That's exactly what synonyms are for.

Comment: Version specific? Bahahahahaha. Well, I'll assist in making the synonym when this one is decided on.

Comment: On reconsidering I think you're right about the synonym. The Anno tag might confuse some people in the US, but the series is much better known as Anno in general. So the tag direction you proposed is fine.

Comment: @Fabian Simply be sure to add the information on the US name into the tag wiki excerpt. Since it shows on hover now, it's a pretty quick way to assist in an unknown tag definition.

Comment: Synonym has been created. Enjoy~ As the #2 answerer, @Fabian, you can write in the initial tag wiki.

Comment: @Grace I'll do that as soon as I'm halfway sober

Comment: @Grace I've added a basic excerpt